# I want to change the particular button html text in jquery but it is not working

Tags: jquery

I want to change the particular button html text in jquery but it is not working
This is My jquery Code Below :

```
<script>
 
$(document).on('click','.track',function() {
  var track_button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'order_track_Data.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data:{track_button_id:track_button_id},
    cache:false,
    beforeSend:function() {
      $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>');
    },
    success:function(data) {
    $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-calendar-week"></i>');
      alert(data.trim());
    }

  })
})

 </script>
```

Comment: Try making a variable for $(this), like `let that = $(this);` before `ajax()` and use that in your functions.

Comment: As comment above: `this` inside `success` is not the same `this` button that was clicked.  While `that=this` is quite common, can be better to be explicit, ie `var btn = $(this);` (as the first line inside the click handler) then use `btn.attr("id")` and `btn.html("<i..`

Comment: As comment above: Plus you can use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to capture `this` inside the inline functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use context for changing the html **

```
<script>
 
$(document).on('click','.track',function() {
  var track_button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'order_track_Data.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data:{track_button_id:track_button_id},
    cache:false,
    context:this,
    beforeSend:function() {
      $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>');
    },
    success:function(data) {
    $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-calendar-week"></i>');
      alert(data.trim());
    }

  })
})

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the comments didn't make it clear:

-note your data object wasn't correct either

```
$(document).on('click','.track',function() {
// assign a variable to the current event target, for later use
  let that = $(this);
  var track_button_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'order_track_Data.php',
    method: 'POST',
// also, you will need to something about the data object
    data:{'track_button_id':track_button_id},
    cache:false,
    beforeSend:function() {
      $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>');
    },
    success:function(data) {
// use the variable defined earlier
    that.html('<i class="fas fa-calendar-week"></i>');
      alert(data.trim());
    }

  })
})
```